# Radeon or AMDGPU for Radeon R7 360?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm using AMD's Tobago chipset on the Radeon R7 360 graphics card. After an unsuccessful attempt to use AMDGPU-PRO I wish to use Radeon or AMDGPU.

I'm using 16.04 and hwe.

```
$ uname -r
4.13.0-36-generic

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago PRO [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Radeon R7 360
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

$ glxinfo
OpenGL renderer string: AMD BONAIRE (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-36-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
```

Radeon appears to support my gpu well with glxgears and webgl in firefox, but there's no hardware acceleration in chrome. Does amdgpu support my gpu and how to enable it instead of radeon?